# Matplotlib does not show some graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to plot a simple graph in Jupyter Notebook with the package matplotlib, I came accross a strange problem that I had never had before.

I've seen that it has hapenned before to other people, and the answers talk about *backends* and other complicated stuff that I can't understand, me having only a rather basic knowledge of Python.

Here comes the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_samples = np.arange(17000)
force_samples = np.arange(17000)

plt.plot(time_samples,force_samples)
plt.show()

time_samples2 = np.random.rand(1,1000)
force_samples2 = np.random.rand(1,1000)

plt.plot(time_samples2,force_samples2)
plt.show()
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

I have no clue why this is happenning.

Comment: You're creating arrays of size `(1,1000)` for the second graph. Try doing `np.random.rand(1000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the array dimension is the issue. x and y should be a 1D array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_samples = np.arange(17000)
force_samples = np.arange(17000)

plt.plot(time_samples,force_samples)
plt.show()

time_samples2 = np.random.rand(1000)
force_samples2 = np.random.rand(1000)

plt.plot(time_samples2,force_samples2)
plt.show()
```

[image]